# jquery .text() returns empty string

Tags: jquery

Not sure why, but with the following Html

```
<div id="basket" class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Basket</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">

            <div id="row-031d9f2b-c6e9-e311-827b-c8bcc8ef428f" class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-8"><span id="qty-031d9f2b-c6e9-e311-827b-c8bcc8ef428f">5</span> <small>x</small> Match Night Ticket [Adult]</div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 text-right">16.00</div>
                <div class="col-xs-2"><a name="removeFromBasket" href="javascript:;" data-pid="031d9f2b-c6e9-e311-827b-c8bcc8ef428f"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger"></span></a></div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8"><strong>Total</strong></div>
            <div id="basket-total" class="col-xs-4">80.00</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I cannot get the value of the span with the id **qty-031d9f2b-c6e9-e311-827b-c8bcc8ef428f**

I'm using the following javascript which returns an empty string. I'm sure I am missing something obvious but after looking at it for an hour or so and trying umpteen variations, I cannot see where I am going wrong.

```
 var qtyId = "qty-" + pid;
                //var productRowId = "#row-" + pid;
                alert($("#basket .panel-body " + qtyId).text());
```

*pid in the script above equals the guid value 031d9f2b-c6e9-e311-827b-c8bcc8ef428f*

Comment: Seaching by ID requires using `#`, I.E. `#qty-031d9f2b-c6e9-e311-827b-c8bcc8ef428f`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the alert to:

```
alert($("#" + qtyId).text());
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/NRRG5/)**

Since IDs must be unique, there's no need to chain them here to get the one you want. And you have to remember to use the `#` to prefix the ID.

Comment: Thanks, how embarrassing. I knew I had spent too long looking at it.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're referring to the element as a top-level element rather than by ID. Using jQuery, with no `.` or `#` selector, the Sizzle selector engine assumes you're referring to an element, such as a `<div>`.

To solve your problem, just add the ID selector in:

```
var qtyId = "qty-" + pid;
//var productRowId = "#row-" + pid;
alert($("#basket .panel-body #" + qtyId).text());
```

The only change there is on the last row, where I have added `#`.